# Is there a way to merge contiguous multilinestrings sf object in R?

Tags: r, r-sf

I hope anyone could help me. Say, I have seven line segments the first four are contiguous as well as the last three. There's no attribute that could be used to group them. Is there a way to merge the first four line segments into a single feature as well as the last three line segment?

Thank you in advance and stay safe!

```
library(sf)

s1 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,3), c(0,4))))
s2 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,4), c(1,5))))
s3 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(1,5), c(2,5))))
s4 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(2,5), c(2.5,5))))
s5 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(2.7,5), c(4,5))))
s6 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(4,5), c(4.5,4))))
s7 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(4.5,4), c(5,4))))

sf_ml <- st_sf(section = 1 ,geometry=st_sfc(list(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7)))
plot(sf_ml)
```

[plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/491gJ.png)

I was hoping to get something like this:

```
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
geometry type:  MULTILINESTRING
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 3 xmax: 5 ymax: 5
CRS:            NA
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  section                                           geometry
*   <dbl>                                  <MULTILINESTRING>
1       1 ((0 3, 0 4), (0 4, 1 5), (1 5, 2 5), (2 5, 2.5 5))
2       1         ((2.7 5, 4 5), (4 5, 4.5 4), (4.5 4, 5 4))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can use the following approach. The idea is to use a
“geometric binary predicate” to calculate groups of connected and contiguous
lines, extract their ID(s), and then merge the lines after grouping by the
ID(s).
First, load packages:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:igraph':
#> 
#>     as_data_frame, groups, union
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

Create data

```r
s1 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,3), c(0,4))))
s2 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(0,4), c(1,5))))
s3 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(1,5), c(2,5))))
s4 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(2,5), c(2.5,5))))
s5 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(2.7,5), c(4,5))))
s6 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(4,5), c(4.5,4))))
s7 <- st_multilinestring(list(rbind(c(4.5,4), c(5,4))))
sf_ml <- st_sf(section = 1 ,geometry=st_sfc(list(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7)))
```

Run st_touches to find the ids of those lines that share a boundary point.

```r
(my_idx_touches <- st_touches(sf_ml))
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 7, where the predicate
#> was `touches'
#>  1: 2
#>  2: 1, 3
#>  3: 2, 4
#>  4: 3
#>  5: 6
#>  6: 5, 7
#>  7: 6
```

We can see that the first and second geometries share a boundary point and so
on. Then, we convert this object into a graph object.

```r
(my_igraph <- graph_from_adj_list(my_idx_touches))
#> IGRAPH fb199d0 D--- 7 10 -- 
#> + edges from fb199d0:
#>  [1] 1->2 2->1 2->3 3->2 3->4 4->3 5->6 6->5 6->7 7->6
```

Again, we can see that the first multilinestring is connected to the second
multilinestring and so on. Finally, we can extract the groups of connected lines using the object named `membership` returned by the output of the function
`components()`.

```r
(my_components <- components(my_igraph)$membership)
#> [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

The first four geometries belong to one group, the other three geometries to
another group. Finally, we can merge the lines in the same group using
summarise()

```r
sf_ml2 <- sf_ml %>% 
  group_by(section = as.character({{my_components}})) %>% 
  summarise()
```

Check the print

```r
sf_ml2
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 3 xmax: 5 ymax: 5
#> CRS:           NA
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   section                                           geometry
#>   <chr>                                    <MULTILINESTRING>
#> 1 1       ((0 3, 0 4), (0 4, 1 5), (1 5, 2 5), (2 5, 2.5 5))
#> 2 2               ((2.7 5, 4 5), (4 5, 4.5 4), (4.5 4, 5 4))
```

and a plot

```r
plot(sf_ml2, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Same question (more or less) and same answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310462/cluster-geometries-that-touch-each-other

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate this. BTW, is there a difference if I use `st_intersects` rather than `st_touches`? Thanks again and stay safe!

Comment: `st_intersects` returns true if two geometries share any portion of space while `st_touches` returns true if two geometries share a boundary point --> `st_touches` is more strict than `st_intersects`.

Comment: The reason I asked is because when I used the same code for contiguous-overlapping polygons, it doesn’t work. But when I used `st_intersects` it worked fine. Anyway, thanks again you’re a big help.

Comment: `st_touches` doesn't "work" for overlapping polygons (unless the only overlapping areas lie in the union of their boundaries). Check https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Touches.html and https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html for more examples

Comment: I see. thanks again!